# Sparkfun Spectrum Shield no change in frequency

Tags: arduino-mega, audio

So i wanted to build a music visualizer using a MSGEQ7. As I just got started with electronics, I did some soldering beforehand and I think I am doing okish. While it might not be perfect, the contact should be fine.

I hooked my arduion MEGA 2560 Board up with the Spectrum Shield and ran the code according to this webpage
https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/spectrum-shield-hookup-guide/all

My solders are fine, however, the serial output for the 7 freuquency bands never changes and stays at 150 once I plug in an aux cable. I checked if the audio is processed at all by connecting a speaker to the output and the music does play. However, there are no changes of the frequency bands when playing music.

Is my board broken? If needed, i can provide pictures of my soldering/circuit. I got pretty frustrated cause I am just getting started and I don't even know how to tell what's wrong.

I really appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Comment: please add your code to your post